# Why does tensorflow r1.9 fail to run cuBLAS routine cublasGemmBatchedEx: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Tensorflow r1.9  compiled for CUDA 9.2 and cudaNN 7.1.4 running in python 3.6 is failing to run a batchedMatMul operation with the following error. I downgraded to Tensorflow r1.8 and the code at [GITHub NN code](https://github.com/IntrepidNomad/NeuralNetwork/blob/master/CapsuleNetwork.py) ran without error. Any ideas why Tensorflow r1.9 is failing?

```
2018-06-10 20:34:38.641901: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2018-06-10 20:34:38.642453: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties:  name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7335 pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0 totalMemory:
7.93GiB freeMemory: 7.71GiB 2018-06-10 20:34:38.642470: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0 2018-06-10 20:34:38.820134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2018-06-10 20:34:38.820170: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:958]      0  2018-06-10 20:34:38.820176: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N  2018-06-10 20:34:38.820372: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7450 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 2018-06-10 20:34:40.605230: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:647] failed to run cuBLAS routine cublasGemmBatchedEx: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED 2018-06-10 20:34:40.606038: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2505] Internal: failed BLAS call, see log for details Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840    [[Node: caps2_predicted = BatchMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/2018-06-10 20:34:38.641901: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2018-06-10 20:34:38.642453: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties:  name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7335 pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0 totalMemory:
7.93GiB freeMemory: 7.71GiB 2018-06-10 20:34:38.642470: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0 2018-06-10 20:34:38.820134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2018-06-10 20:34:38.820170: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:958]      0  2018-06-10 20:34:38.820176: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N  2018-06-10 20:34:38.820372: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7450 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 2018-06-10 20:34:40.605230: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:647] failed to run cuBLAS routine cublasGemmBatchedEx: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED 2018-06-10 20:34:40.606038: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2505] Internal: failed BLAS call, see log for details Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840    [[Node: caps2_predicted = BatchMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled)]]   [[Node: loss/_47 =
_Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_893_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "CapsuleNetwork.py", line 476, in <module>
    mask_with_labels: True})   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840     [[Node: caps2_predicted = BatchMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled)]]   [[Node: loss/_47 =
_Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_893_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'caps2_predicted', defined at:   File "CapsuleNetwork.py", line 207, in <module>
    name="caps2_predicted")   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1976, in matmul
    a, b, adj_x=adjoint_a, adj_y=adjoint_b, name=name)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1236, in batch_mat_mul
    "BatchMatMul", x=x, y=y, adj_x=adj_x, adj_y=adj_y, name=name)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3206, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1701, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840    [[Node: caps2_predicted = BatchMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled)]]   [[Node: loss/_47 =
_Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_893_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]] device:GPU:0"](W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled)]]    [[Node: loss/_47 =
_Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_893_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "CapsuleNetwork.py", line 476, in <module>
    mask_with_labels: True})   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840     [[Node: caps2_predicted = BatchMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled)]]   [[Node: loss/_47 =
_Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_893_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'caps2_predicted', defined at:   File "CapsuleNetwork.py", line 207, in <module>
    name="caps2_predicted")   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1976, in matmul
    a, b, adj_x=adjoint_a, adj_y=adjoint_b, name=name)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1236, in batch_mat_mul
    "BatchMatMul", x=x, y=y, adj_x=adj_x, adj_y=adj_y, name=name)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3206, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1701, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840    [[Node: caps2_predicted = BatchMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled)]]   [[Node: loss/_47 =
_Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_893_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block` instead of >>quotes

Comment: `Blas xGEMMBatched launch failed : a.shape=[675840,16,8], b.shape=[675840,8,1], m=16, n=1, k=8, batch_size=675840` ...that's a suspiciously big batch size. Could it be you're running out of memory?

Comment: I've run the same code on a 3GB GPU without problems. I am running it on a 1080 8GB now. Unless the behavior of tf.matmul has changed. It is a bit odd because in the code the tensors being multiplied are of rank 5 and not rank 3. The actual batch size is only 10 and there are only 5940 examples in the dataset.

Comment: Could you put together a snippet to reproduce? If this is a regression across TF versions it'd be good to track down.